# What's wrong with my liquibase changelog?

Tags: mysql, spring, yaml, liquibase

I'm trying to learn how to use liquibase to update my database schema if MySQL. I've created an empty schema in the Workbench and in my spring project I have:

application.properties (resources package):

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.yaml
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice
spring.datasource.username=maxim
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

In this file I'm sure about url, username, password and path to changelog-master are correct.

My changelog-master.yaml is in (resources/db/changelog package)

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: changelog_1.yaml
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

And finally, my changelog_1.yaml(resources/db/changelog package):

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: maxim
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: Device
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: BIGINT
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: name
                  type: VARCHAR
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```

When I try to execute the program, I get:

```
liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:1 change sets check sum
          classpath:db/changelog/changelog_1.yaml::1::maxim was: 8:8896ac0d055b8ae982733866bc5682b1 but is now: 8:1e0167b7454bbfa9b38e2c11740cadee
```

Is there a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto in my application.properties file to 'create-drop' and it worked